# Netbeans: Navigate-> Go To Declaration/Definition BROKEN with "Cannot Open Element" on C++ 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, netbeans, editor, inspect

My Netbeans right-click Navigate -> Go to Declaration/Definition is broken, it refuses to go anywhere.  Instead, in the lower left-hand corner, a message pops up: 'Cannot open element: "myvariablename".'  It does not matter if the variable or function I have selected to inspect is remote, global, or local to the function.  Neither does it work from the upper menu Navigate -> Go to Declaration/Definition.

Netbeans is using the GNU C++ toolchain on a 64-bit Ubuntu 13.10 AMD.  It uses make, compiles, and runs the complex C++ projects correctly.

I upgraded and installed a new version of Netbeans 8.0 to get rid of this, but it still happens.

There are some few cases in which it works correctly, but I have not been able to tell the difference yet.  When the code does not compile and link all the way, it seems to be worse.  It may be project-dependent.  I could understand getting lost if the project does not compile and link, but it certainly has enough information to know where everything is.

I do not have any such problems with my other 32-bit Ubuntu machine running Netbeans 8.0.  I guess it is some kind of configuration issue.

How do I get Netbeans to be able to successfully go to the source definitions of variables and functions under C++ projects?  Thank you.

Comment: There's an update for NB 8.0 these days (incl. some patches for C/C++ parts).

Comment: Running the update patches trashes 35 APIs, including the C/C++ Code Model Implementation Module. I have to fall back to reinstalling the latest 8.0, a 212MB download.

Comment: Running the 8.0 full installer's defaults creates directory netbeansnetbeans-8.0 [sic] in home directory.  Not impressive.  Desktop icon no longer launches NB. Running netbeans script nor executable directly no longer launches. Installer has no deinstall option. I deleted the directory structure, including executables. Installer refuses to reinstall 8.0 modules, saying they're already installed.  Installer refuses to go forward, even in custom panel, unless it's installing something.  Checkmate.

Comment: Falling back to stable version 7.0.1 from Synaptic.  Runs from desktop icon. Whines about possible corruption but recovers newer project successfully.  After switching project->Properties->Run->Console Type back to Standard Output, compiles, links, and runs.  Navigation to inspect source still broken.

Comment: o.O Oh dear! Have tested a *clean* installation of NB8.0 (deleting / renaming the config directories of NB8 in your home dir)? Was there any errormessage or logfile?

Comment: Btw. the list of bugs fixed in update 1: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?status_whiteboard=80patch1&status_whiteboard_type=allwordssubstr

Comment: It's doing it again, now, on a different machine, with 8.0.  Seems to be all the way across the board, previous projects that were working now can no longer search.

Comment: One site suggests "Please try to close NetBeans, delete cache dir /home/user/.cache/netbeans/8.0rc1 and start NetBeans again."

Comment: Did this suggestion help?

Comment: Yes.  See below.  It's now an official answer.  Apparently there are some cases in which it doesn't work, but it did the trick for me. I've been waiting for the answer to this for two years, various versions have been broken for that long.  Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, i think this may help some users.

Comment: I also tried removing the cache, didn't work. I've also struggled with this issue over several releases of Netbeans (v7, v8, v8.2 and most recently v12.5). It's essentially broken. Sometimes it works perfectly, sometimes it works only if the referenced  element is in the same file, and sometimes not al all. I love Netbeans' somewhat minimalist approach compared to the bloated mess that Eclipse has become. But correct indexing is an IDE's most essential feature; without this it is useless. I've now given up on NB, and gone to Eclipse. It seems that official C++ support stopped with v8.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Please try to **close** NetBeans, **delete** cache dir 
`/home/user/.cache/netbeans/8.0rc1` 
and start NetBeans again."

This worked for me this time.

Comment: Works for many projects, does not work for some projects that compile and link. Can't tell difference.  There were two different paths to an include .h with the same name, but this possible stumbling block got cleaned up and that project still doesn't work.  It does look like today at least it's project-dependent, although I think I've seen cases in which the contagion spreads across projects spontaneously.

Comment: Project-dependent.  Didn't work for NB 8.0 on a particular project.  There is some thought that mixing C code with C++ code may bollix the system, although this hypothesis is unverified.

Comment: worked also for nb11, that cache was recreated w/o problems

Comment: Doesn't work for NB v12.5

Comment: dosen't work für nb 20

Answer (score 0):

On the "Projects" tab, right click in one of the top projects folder and select:
`Code assistance / reparse project`

btw, I am using netbeans 11 with C++ plugin (this plugin is from nb8 as I remember but works very well).