# netbeans can't find C++ header file in same directory

Tags: c++, netbeans, autocomplete

In one particular cpp file (abc.cpp), when I ask to navigate "to Declaration/Definition", it says "cannot open element "abc.h"". This functionality works for other header files. This in itself is not a big problem, but it also means that auto-complete and syntax highlighting doesn't work for this file.

Some extra info:

- The header file is in the same directory as the cpp file and both are included in the active netbeans project
- I was able to enter the header file name with auto-complete, i.e. `#include "ab<ctrl-space>"`
- clicking the "Go to header/source" button works both ways for this cpp/h pair.
- right-clicking on the class name in the header file, and then selecting "go to source" brings me to the cpp file, as usual.
- in other cpp files the connection to the header file is working fine, as is autocomplete & syntax highlighting
- netbeans has a green square in the top right of the header file window, indicating "no errors"
- I have tried deleting my cache as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26936893/1295595)
- I'm using netbeans v8.0.2 on OpenSuse 13.2

Comment: Is abc.cpp  in a project created by Netbeans? If so which kind of project? Is the header file listed in the Header Files node of the tree in the Projects tab?

Comment: Thanks for your questions. Originally the project was created from existing sources. `abc.cpp` and `abc.h` (and other files) were added later. I think I used `right-click --> new --> C++ class` in the Projects tab to create the files. Autocomplete & syntax highlighting work for all the other files, but I can't spot any differences.

I keep `cpp` and `h` files together in a folder called `Src`. There is no Header Files node in the tree in the Projects tab.

Comment: When working in netbeans, do everything netbeans way. I faced a similar situation when I copy-pasted a header and its companion implementation file into the current netbeans C project directory. Every time build error. Then I created the header file from right clicking the Header files section and its implementation from the Source files section and the project built successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

- Sometimes the Code Assistance is not as good for projects that Netbeans didn't create from scratch. If it is not a complicated Makefile, it might be worth it to create a new project with the C/C++ Application type and copy over and then add each source and header file.
- The code assistance depends on analyzing he log from the build each time, so sometimes just rebuilding the project will fix the code assistance.
- There are a number of options if you right click the project under the code assistance sub-menu.
- Edit the Makefile to make sure this file is being compiled in the same way as the other files that work. It may be getting compiled with different options because it was added later and therefore not providing the same info for code assistance. You will need to rebuild after making these changes for them to have an effect.

Comment: Thanks, that's a bunch of good ideas. What worked for me was the 2nd one. I had errors in one of the other files in the project (lets call that file `123.cpp`), and the compilation never got as far as the `abc.cpp`, so of course there was nothing in the build log for the code assistance. After moving `123.cpp` out of the project and restarting netbeans, syntax highlighting appeared instantly. When I added `123.cpp` back and restarted netbeans, the problem returned, i.e. syntax highlighting disappeared...

Comment: I hadn't thought that compilation errors in file A could affect code assistance in file B. I also didn't expect that SO many things could go wrong with code assistance. I definitely wouldn't have cracked it without those ideas, and I'm sure the other tips will helpful for somebody else too.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue too, but my solution is a little different. I found that the header file is not located at the place where the project browser indicates. So I opened terminal to move it to the place where it is supposed to be, and then the problem is solved!